# Number Format Exception Error logic help don't see the issue

Tags: java, object, methods, while-loop

Getting a number format exception error when trying to design and exit command in my expression string. advice would be tremendously appreciated :).

```html
String expression = " ";
//all other varaible in loop are declared and intialized
//removed for cluttering purposes
while(!expression.equals("QUIT"))
        {
            expression = kbd.nextLine();
            variable = expression.charAt(0);
            startIndex = expression.lastIndexOf(" ")+1;//index of future integer value 
            StringLength = expression.length();
            strValue = expression.substring(startIndex,StringLength);
            intValue = Integer.parseInt(strValue);//ERROR HERE numberFormatException
        }
        System.out.println(" "+strValue);//STRING VALUE TEST PRINT
        tempIndex.put(variable,intValue);//assigns int value to variable
        int getVarValue = tempIndex.get(variable);//gets value stored in variable 
        System.out.println(variable+" = "+getVarValue);
```

Comment: Show us which line of your code is throwing the exception.

Comment: And post the complete stack trace of the exception. Every exception trouble-shooting starts b reading such a stack trace. Also, given that everything depends on what is read from the keyboard, and you didn't say anything about it, we can't help. Print the value of your variables, or use a debugger, and you'll know.

Comment: did you try to put a debug pointer and debug?

Comment: So what value of `expression` is giving you the exception?  Without this information, the question is completely meaningless.

Comment: There is not error for the expression. I know the issue is with the while loop, why i do not know. I do not know how to trace something. my error is on my parseInt line.

Comment: If you don't tell us the value of `expression` when you get the error, then all anybody can do is guess.  But that error occurs when you call `parseInt` and pass it an argument that isn't a number.

Answer (score 1):

Java complains that you are not giving her an integer here:

```
intValue = Integer.parseInt(strValue);
```

for instance if I just run

```
Integer.parseInt("1a");
```

I will get an error as `parseInt` will not make it `1` for you, it will just throw this exception saying that it does not know what to do in this case,

You can try verifying string first before trying to parse it. Regular expressions come handy here. If you do not know regular expressions just check that all chars in string are either '0', '1', '2', ... '9'. if something else is encounter you just do not call `parseInt` method

Comment: Your suppose to sen parse a string..I do not understand what you're saying

Comment: it is a integer I'm printing it out

Comment: Sorry, can you clarify what you do not understand please